# How to validate the length of elements inside List using javax.validation.constraints in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, bean-validation, javax.validation

How to validate the length of elements inside List using javax.validation.constraints in Spring. Right now @Size is validating on the list size, not on the inside elements.

```
class RequestInputParamaters {

        @NotNull
        @NotEmpty
        @Size(min = 1, max=4)
        List documentIdentifier_value

    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
List<@NotNull @NotEmpty @Size(min = 1, max=4) String> documentIdentifier_value;
```

If using `hibernate-validator`, you'll need version 6+.

Legacy solution:

```
@Valid List<StringWrapper> documentIdentifier_value;
```

where `StringWrapper` is defined as:

```
public class StringWrapper {
    @NotNull @NotEmpty @Size(min = 1, max=4)
    private String wrapped;
    ...
}
```