# How to apply validation to elements of a collection type

Tags: java, spring, collections, javax.validation

I'm using spring, and thus `javax.validation`, so that's context of this question.

Suppose I want to validate that the elements of a list only contain 4 digit numbers.

I would like to code:

```
@Min(1000)
@Max(9999)
List<Integer> numbers;
```

but validation explodes complaining that `@Min` and `@Max` can't be used to validate a `List`. OK, makes sense.

I could use `@Valid` on a list of custom objects, eg:

```
@Valid // validate each element
List<My4DigitNumberClass> numbers;

@MyCustom4DigitValidation
class My4DigitNumberClass {
    Integer number;
}
```

but I just want to use `Integer` (and eventually other boxed primitives, Strings, etc), something like:

```
@ValidateElements({ @Min(1000), @Max(9999) })
List<Integer> numbers;
```

Can I do this without creating any custom classes or custom validation annotations?

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to validate the length of elements inside List using javax.validation.constraints in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939444/how-to-validate-the-length-of-elements-inside-list-using-javax-validation-constr)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Annotate the *type*, using this syntax:

```
List<@Min(1000) @Max(9999) Integer> numbers;
```