# Spring boot validate each string in a List (kotlin)

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, hibernate-validator, spring-validator, spring-kotlin

I'm struggling with validation in String Boot.

I have the following class in Kotlin:

```kotlin
class ListBlock(
    @field:Size(max = 5)
    val style: String,

    @field:Valid
    @field:Size(max = 10)
    val items: List<@Size(max = 50) String>
)
```

`@field:Size(max = 5)` on style works fine by having size > 5

`@field:Size(max = 10)` on items works fine by having more than 10 strings in the list

I don't get any errors if one of the strings in the list has a size larger than 50 characters.

Comment: Already tried the  @Length annotation?

Comment: No, but I tried now. Works the same way as @Size

Comment: What version of hibernate-validator do you use?

Comment: I'm using spring.boot.starter.validation:2.3.4.RELEASE 
org.hibernate.validator:6.1.5.Final

Comment: Already tried this?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49941439/7919904

Comment: No, not really, but putting all strings into StringWrapper sounds like a dirty workaround for something that should work.

Comment: found a solution?

Answer (score 5):

You have to compile to Java 1.8 or higher (for bytecode to support type annotations), and use Kotlin 1.3.70 or higher with the option `-Xemit-jvm-type-annotations` for it to work...

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13228

Comment: Worked for me in Kotlin 1.8 setup and target Java version 17, thanks!