# Bean validation can validate both size of a List and maximum length of each elements

Tags: java, json, bean-validation

How can I set a bean validation constraint that a List should at minimum contain 1 and at maximum contain 4 elements, at the same time, check the maximum length of each elements

the following annotation only works for minItems, maxItems, while how to constrain the  the maximum length of each elements

@Size(min=1, max=4)
private List list;

"list": [
"String1",
"String2",
"String3"
]

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please take a peek at this Question/Answer and see if that helps:  [How to validate the length of elements inside List using javax.validation.constraints in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49939444/42962)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate the length of elements inside List using javax.validation.constraints in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939444/how-to-validate-the-length-of-elements-inside-list-using-javax-validation-constr)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the annotation will work on just the list of objects. So I suggest adding a new class and defining a String field that has a @Size(min= 10).
Here is what I mean:

```
public class InputString{
       @Size(min = 10, message =  "{validation.name.size.too_long}")
       private String input;
}
```

Then use it:

```
@Size(min=1, max=4)
 private List<InputString> list;
```

Comment: while the incoming json payload structure is :      "StringList": ["String1", "String2", "String3"],  can not change the element to Java object.

Comment: So you have to iterate the list and check the length of each String  in a for each.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add a method to the object that will be part of the validation.

```
@AssertTrue
private boolean isList() {
    return list.stream().noneMatch(s -> s.length() > 20 || s.length() < 3);
}
```